# Reading XML file and fetching its attributes value in Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, python-2.7

I have this XML file:

```
<domain type='kmc' id='007'>
  <name>virtual bug</name>
  <uuid>66523dfdf555dfd</uuid>
  <os>
    <type arch='xintel' machine='ubuntu'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  </os>
  <memory unit='KiB'>524288</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>270336</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>10</vcpu>
```

Now, I want parse this and fetch its attribute value. For instance, I want to fetch the `uuid` field. So what should be the proper method to fetch it, in Python?

Comment: What have you tried? Googling "python xml" yields quite a few really useful results that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: there are a lot of examples but not pointing in the direction i want to go. I wnat to fetch attributes value. the examples i am seeing are to convert to xml file or to convert form an xml file

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's an **[lxml](http://lxml.de/)** snippet that extracts an *attribute* as well as element *text* (your question was a little ambiguous about which one you needed, so I'm including both):

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse(filename)

memoryElem = doc.find('memory')
print memoryElem.text        # element text
print memoryElem.get('unit') # attribute
```

You asked (in a comment on Ali Afshar's answer) whether **minidom** ([2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html), [3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)) is a good alternative.  Here's the equivalent code using minidom; judge for yourself which is nicer:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
doc = minidom.parse(filename)

memoryElem = doc.getElementsByTagName('memory')[0]
print ''.join( [node.data for node in memoryElem.childNodes] )
print memoryElem.getAttribute('unit')
```

lxml seems like the winner to me.

Comment: This method is also compatible with [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), which is included with Python 2 and 3.

Comment: The first try with lxml does not work for me ... when I want to acces .text it says that Nonetype object has no attribute 'text'.

Answer (score 13):

**XML**

```
<data>
    <items>
        <item name="item1">item1</item>
        <item name="item2">item2</item>
        <item name="item3">item3</item>
        <item name="item4">item4</item>
    </items>
</data>
```

**Python :**

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('items.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item') 
print "Len : ", len(itemlist)
print "Attribute Name : ", itemlist[0].attributes['name'].value
print "Text : ", itemlist[0].firstChild.nodeValue
for s in itemlist :
    print "Attribute Name : ", s.attributes['name'].value
    print "Text : ", s.firstChild.nodeValue
```

Answer (score 2):

etree, with [lxml](http://lxml.de/) probably:

```
root = etree.XML(MY_XML)
uuid = root.find('uuid')
print uuid.text
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use lxml and parse it out using `xpath //UUID`

Answer (score 0):

Other people can tell you how to do it with the Python standard library. I'd recommend my own mini-library that makes this a completely straight forward.

```
>>> obj = xml2obj.xml2obj("""<domain type='kmc' id='007'>
... <name>virtual bug</name>
... <uuid>66523dfdf555dfd</uuid>
... <os>
... <type arch='xintel' machine='ubuntu'>hvm</type>
... <boot dev='hd'/>
... <boot dev='cdrom'/>
... </os>
... <memory unit='KiB'>524288</memory>
... <currentMemory unit='KiB'>270336</currentMemory>
... <vcpu placement='static'>10</vcpu>
... </domain>""")
>>> obj.uuid
u'66523dfdf555dfd'
```

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/534109-xml-to-python-data-structure/

Answer (score 0):

Above XML does not have closing tag, It will give

> etree parse error: Premature end of data in tag

Correct XML is:

```
<domain type='kmc' id='007'>
  <name>virtual bug</name>
  <uuid>66523dfdf555dfd</uuid>
  <os>
    <type arch='xintel' machine='ubuntu'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  </os>
  <memory unit='KiB'>524288</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>270336</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>10</vcpu>
</domain>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try parsing it with using (recover=True).
you can do something like this.

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = etree.parse('your xml file', parser)
```

I used this recently and it worked for me, you can try and see but in case you need to do any more complecated xml data extractions, you can take a look at this code i wrote for some project [handling complex xml data extractions.](https://github.com/edmondsylar/complex_xml)