# XML parsing specific values - Python

Tags: python, xml

I've been attempting to parse a list of xml files. I'd like to print specific values such as the `userName` value.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Drives clsid="{8FDDCC1A-0C3C-43cd-A6B4-71A6DF20DA8C}" 
        disabled="1">
  <Drive clsid="{935D1B74-9CB8-4e3c-9914-7DD559B7A417}" 
         name="S:" 
         status="S:" 
         image="2" 
         changed="2007-07-06 20:57:37" 
         uid="{4DA4A7E3-F1D8-4FB1-874F-D2F7D16F7065}">
    <Properties action="U" 
                thisDrive="NOCHANGE" 
                allDrives="NOCHANGE" 
                userName="" 
                cpassword="" 
                path="\\scratch" 
                label="SCRATCH" 
                persistent="1" 
                useLetter="1" 
                letter="S"/>
  </Drive>
</Drives>
```

My script is working fine collecting a list of xml files etc. However the below function is to print the relevant values. I'm trying to achieve this as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290091/reading-xml-file-and-fetching-its-attributes-value-in-python). However I'm clearly doing something incorrectly as I'm getting errors suggesting that `elm` object has no attribute `text`. Any help would be appreciated.

**Current Code**

```
from lxml import etree as ET

def read_files(files):
    for fi in files:
        doc = ET.parse(fi)
        elm = doc.find('userName')
        print elm.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doc.find` looks for a **tag** with the given name. You are looking for an **attribute** with the given name.

`elm.text` is giving you an error because `doc.find` doesn't find any tags, so it returns `None`, which has no `text` property.

Read the lxml.etree docs some more, and then try something like this:

```
doc = ET.parse(fi)
root = doc.getroot()
prop = root.find(".//Properties") # finds the first <Properties> tag anywhere
elm = prop.attrib['userName']
```

Comment: Eh? It's not the root that the attribute hangs off of.

Comment: You're quite right, I fixed my answer to look for the attribute of the `Properties` tag instead.

Answer (score 1):

`userName` is an attribute, not an element. Attributes don't have text nodes attached to them at all.

```
for el in doc.xpath('//*[@userName]'):
  print el.attrib['userName']
```

Comment: could you please explain the `//*[@userName]` value? Id like to understand how to add multiple attributes.

Comment: @iNoob, you should read the `etree` docs for how to use an XPath-like specification to find tags with specific attributes: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath

Comment: @DanLenski, ...oh, that's a fair objection -- I was using real XPath here; in practice, I use `lxml.etree`, not the standard-library ElementTree.

Comment: @DanLenski, ...actually, rereading the question, the OP is using lxml.etree, so it's actually a fair call. :)

Comment: Oh, I'm not objecting! I prefer `lxml.etree` myself. I simply pointed the OP to the stdlib `etree` docs because they give a simple, concise summary of the XPath strings, and the `lxml` version is basically a superset of that behavior.

Comment: @iNoob, `@userName` means "having an attribute called userName". `//` does a recursive search. `*` matches an element with any name. That said, if you know that the element with the properties you want will always be called Properties, then you don't need to search off of which attributes it has.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take the element using the tag name and then try to take its attribute (`userName` is an attribute for `Properties`):

```
from lxml import etree as ET

def read_files(files):
    for fi in files:
        doc = ET.parse(fi)
        props = doc.getElementsByTagName('Properties') 
        elm = props[0].attributes['userName']
        print elm.value
```