# Access into a tag in xml with python

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to get the information of this tag:

```
<movie:actor rdf:resource="http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/actor/32439"/>
```

I need the final numbers (32439) but if i get the url I will be happy too.

I know how to get, for example, this information between this tags:

`<dc:title>Eragon</dc:title>`

with

```
Title=catalogo.getElementsByTagName("dc:title")[0]
print Title.childNodes[0].data
```

But i can't do the same with the other one,

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290091/reading-xml-file-and-fetching-its-attributes-value-in-python and http://www.diveintopython.net/xml_processing/attributes.html