# Extracting xml data

Tags: python, xml, string

I would like to extract some data from an XML file. Here is the XML file:
`<post height="4093" score="14" file_url="xxxx" parent_id="" sample_url="xxxx" sample_width="850" sample_height="1202 />"`

All I need is to extract the string that is stored `file_url`. I want this `"xxxx"`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12293187/10325004
Does this  help you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xml.etree.ElementTree` xml parser:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<post height="4093" score="14" file_url="xxxx" parent_id="" sample_url="xxxx" sample_width="850" sample_height="1202" />'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.attrib['file_url'])
```