# Is there a way to extract data based on keyword from XML?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Catalog>
   <CatalogItemLine>
     <NameValue name="Car_id">111-2020-3</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Car Name">Honda Accord</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Price at location 98134">40000</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="type">Gas</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Mpg">30</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="color">blue</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="door">4</NameValue>
     
   </CatalogItemLine>
   <CatalogItemLine>
     <NameValue name="Car_id">121-2020-3</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Car Name">Honda Civic</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Price at location 98134">30000</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="type">Gas</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Mpg">35</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="color">white</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="door">2</NameValue>
   </CatalogItemLine>
   <CatalogItemLine>
     <NameValue name="Car_id">131-2020-3</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Car Name">Toyota Camry</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Price at location 98134">45000</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="type">Gas</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Mpg">32</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="color">black</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="door">4</NameValue>
   </CatalogItemLine>
   <CatalogItemLine>
     <NameValue name="Car_id">151-2020-3</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Car Name">Honda Pilot</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Price at location 98134">50000</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="type">Gas</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Mpg">30</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="color">gray</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="door">4</NameValue>
   </CatalogItemLine>
   <CatalogItemLine>
     <NameValue name="Car_id">101-2020-3</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Car Name">Chevy Malibu</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Price at location 98134">40000</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="type">Gas</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Mpg">30</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="color">white</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="door">4</NameValue>
   </CatalogItemLine>
</Catalog>
```

**I am trying to fetch the data which contains keyword "**Honda**" in xml file.
Only trying to fetch **(Car_id, Car Name, Price at location 98134, Mpg)**.
**Output I want to get is:****

```
**Car_id
111-2020-3
Car Name
Honda Accord
Price at location 98134
40000
Mpg
30

Car_id
121-2020-3
Car Name
Honda Civic
Price at location 98134
30000
Mpg
35

Car_id
151-2020-3
Car Name
Honda Pilot
Price at location 98134
50000
Mpg
30**
```

Code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile= ('cardata.xml')


tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

    for CatalogItemLine in root.findall('.//CatalogItemLine'):
        if CatalogItemLine.find('NameValue') is not None:
           NameValue = CatalogItemLine.find('NameValue')
           if NameValue.text is not None:
               if "Honda" in NameValue.text:
                   print(CatalogItemLine.find('NameValue').text)
```

I was unable to get output, I just started learning and using python and XML.

I am trying to fetch the data which contains keyword "Honda" in xml file.

Only trying to fetch the following data (Car_id, Car Name, Price at location 98134, Mpg).

Highly appreciate your HELP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12293187/2834978

Comment: Why are you looping over a filename?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mzjn all tags are there: <Catalog>
   <CatalogItemLine><NameValue></NameValue></CatalogItemLine></Catalog>

Comment: @mzjn sorry my bad, I just updated the xml. Can you please help me with the output?

Comment: XML is fine now, but the `for` loop block in the Python code is badly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Catalog>
   <CatalogItemLine>
     <NameValue name="Car_id">111-2020-3</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Car Name">Honda Accord</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Price at location 98134">40000</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="type">Gas</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Mpg">30</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="color">blue</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="door">4</NameValue>
     
   </CatalogItemLine>
   <CatalogItemLine>
     <NameValue name="Car_id">121-2020-3</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Car Name">Honda Civic</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Price at location 98134">30000</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="type">Gas</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Mpg">35</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="color">white</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="door">2</NameValue>
   </CatalogItemLine>
   <CatalogItemLine>
     <NameValue name="Car_id">131-2020-3</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Car Name">Toyota Camry</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Price at location 98134">45000</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="type">Gas</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Mpg">32</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="color">black</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="door">4</NameValue>
   </CatalogItemLine>
   <CatalogItemLine>
     <NameValue name="Car_id">151-2020-3</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Car Name">Honda Pilot</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Price at location 98134">50000</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="type">Gas</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Mpg">30</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="color">gray</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="door">4</NameValue>
   </CatalogItemLine>
   <CatalogItemLine>
     <NameValue name="Car_id">101-2020-3</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Car Name">Chevy Malibu</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Price at location 98134">40000</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="type">Gas</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="Mpg">30</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="color">white</NameValue>
     <NameValue name="door">4</NameValue>
   </CatalogItemLine>
</Catalog>  '''
properties = ['Car_id', 'Car Name', 'Price at location 98134', 'Mpg']
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = []
for cil in root.findall('.//CatalogItemLine'):
    nv = cil.find('NameValue[@name="Car Name"]')
    if 'honda' in nv.text.lower():
        entry = {}
        for p in properties:
            entry[p] = cil.find(f'NameValue[@name="{p}"]').text
        data.append(entry)
for entry in data:
    print(entry)
```

output

```
{'Car_id': '111-2020-3', 'Car Name': 'Honda Accord', 'Price at location 98134': '40000', 'Mpg': '30'}
{'Car_id': '121-2020-3', 'Car Name': 'Honda Civic', 'Price at location 98134': '30000', 'Mpg': '35'}
{'Car_id': '151-2020-3', 'Car Name': 'Honda Pilot', 'Price at location 98134': '50000', 'Mpg': '30'}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution really appreciate your help,  I have one doubt, I have multiple XML files which contain data in such a way that ( file "c1.xml" contains data for Honda Accord, file "c2.xml" contains data for Honda Civic, file "c3.xml" contains data for Toyota Camry, file "c4.xml" contains data for Honda Pilot).   my code is reading those files but the issue is it is grabbing data from the last file which is "c4.xml". I want that it should grab the data from all the files which contains "Honda".

Comment: so you need to loop over the files list and grab the honda from each one. Anyway - in your question you did not mention multiple files so my answer covers well your question. Please accept the answer.